# res.statusCode giving undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Any pointers in the right direction much appreciated, I am use node/express and still a beginner at it, trying to re-use some code from a previous working project but have gotten stuck.

Trying to access an API that would be used for verifying emails but the response is not giving me the statusCode I expect.

```
var request = require('request');

var ValidEmailApiURL = "(path to api)";



 module.exports = {

 verifyEmailAPI: function(emailToken) {

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      request({
       url: ValidEmailApiURL ,
       method: 'PUT'
      }, function(err, res, body) {


   console.log(res.statusCode);


       if (err) reject(err);
       if (res.statusCode === 200) {
          return resolve(body);
        } else if (res.statusCode === 404) {
          return reject(body);
          //return resolve(body);
        }
      });
    });
  }


};
```

I am expecting res.statusCode to give me 404 but it instead gives me underfined.
The API url, through postman returns a response like so:

```
{ "statusCode": 404, "message": "Resource not found" }
```

thanks

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise

Comment: what does `console.log(err)` say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an error occurs, you might not necessarily get a status code back.  The `err` object might tell you more about what is happening here.

Comment: thank you, best answers are always the obvious ones! err is giving me an connection refused so it gives me somewhere to start from.